# Complement of image of an entire, holomorphic map contains an open disk implies the map is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show the above in order to then use Liouville's Theorem and conclude the map is constant. Thus, I am not sure that the entirety of the map is necessary.

$\exists B(x, r) \subseteq f(\mathbb{C})^c \rightarrow \exists M \in \mathbb{R} \space \forall x \in \mathbb{C} \space |f(x)| \le M$

Comment: Hint: For an entire $f$, either image of $f$ is an open set or a singleton set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**: Say the open disk in the complement is $|w-w_0|<r$. What can you say about the function $g(z)=\dfrac1{f(z)-w_0}$?